# Holomorphic function which goes to zero on the boundary of an annulus is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $0<r<s<\infty$, $A:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:r<|z|<s\}$, and $f$ is holomorphic on $A$. Suppose that (a) $f(z_n)\to 0$ for every sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $A$ with $|z_n|\to r$ or (b) $f(z_n)\to 0$ for every sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $A$ with $|z_n|\to s$. Prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in A$.

I am interpreting the "or" here to mean that if either (a) or (b) holds, then we must show that $f\equiv 0$.

Some partial progress/ideas:

It would be nice if we could extend $f$ to be defined on all of $\overline{A}$. We could define $f(z)=0$ for when $|z_n|=r$ or $s$ in the case (a) or (b) respectively, but since (a) and (b) do not both hold in general, I do not see how this extension would necessarily be continuous. Furthermore, after we obtain such an extension, we probably want to do some sort of maximum/minimum modulus type argument on the boundary, but this requires something even stronger, namely that the function is in fact holomorphic. In any case, I am not sure how one would actually achieve this.

Since such an extension might end up identically zero on at least one part of the boundary of $A$, it appears that the fact that zeros of an analytic function are isolated might come into play as well. But I do not know how one would take advantage of this exactly.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Assume for simplicity that $r=1$, and that $f(z_n) \to 0$ for every sequence in $A$ with $z_n \to 1$.  $f$ has an analytic continuation $F$ to the larger annulus $1/s < |z| < s$, by defining
$$
 F(z) = \begin{cases}
 f(z) & \text{ for } 1 < |z| < s \, ,\\
 0 &  \text{ for }  |z| = 1 \, ,\\
 \overline{f(1/\bar z)} & \text{ for } 1/s < |z| < 1 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
The holomorphy of $F$ follows from [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) or the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle).

Now the identity theorem shows that $F$ – and consequently $f$ – is identically zero.

Comment: I don't quite see how this method can be generalized for arbitrary $r$ (except an ugly case-by-case consideration based on whether $r$ and $s$ are greater than or less than $1$). Is there no easier way of finding an analytic continuation?

Comment: Additionally, how exactly does the holomorphicity of $F$ follow from Morera? Why must it be true that the integral of $F$ vanishes along every nice contour?

Comment: @ragamuffin: For the general case replace $f(z)$ by $f(z/r)$ or $f(s/z)$. – For Morera's theorem it suffices to consider triangle paths. If such a triangle crosses $|z|=1$ then you can split the integral into two: One inside $|z| \le1$ and one inside $|z| \ge1$. Both are zero for continuity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using symmetrization and truncation, not analytic continuation.

*nice case*:
suppose $f:A' \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ where $A' = \big\{z: r' \lt \vert z\vert\lt \frac{1}{r'}\big\}$, and $f$ is analytic in $A'$ and continuous on $\partial A'$, and we know $f$ is zero for $\vert z \vert =r'\neq 0$. Then $F(z):=f(z)\cdot f(z^{-1})$ is analytic in $A'$ and is the zero function per max modulus theorem $\implies f$ has an uncountable number of zeros $\implies f$ is the zero function on its Domain $A'$.

*general case:*
We can assume WLOG that OP's limit criterion applies for the "inner boundary" $r$ (why?).
$g(z)= f\big(r\cdot z\big)$ is defined on the annulus $\big\{z: 1 \lt \vert z\vert\lt \frac{s}{r}\big\}$.  Then $G(z):=g\big((1+\delta)\cdot z\big)$ is defined on the annulus $\big\{z: \frac{1}{1+\delta} \lt \vert z\vert\lt \frac{1}{1+\delta} \cdot\frac{s}{r}\big\}$ and by selecting $\delta \gt 0$ small enough --i.e. pick some  $\delta \in \big(0,\sqrt{\frac{s}{r}}-1\big)$-- we may truncate this annulus to $A' := \big\{z: \frac{1}{1+\delta} \lt \vert z\vert\lt 1+\delta\lt \frac{1}{1+\delta} \cdot\frac{s}{r}\big\}$.  When restricted to $A'$ we see $G$ is analytic in the interior, continuous on the boundary and identically zero on the inner boundary; per the nice case $G$ is the zero function on $A'$, hence on all of its Domain thus $g$ and $f$ are identically zero on their Domain.

Comment: This is a nice proof. You can simplify the argument at bit: Choose $s'$ with $r < s' < s$. Then $f(z) \cdot f(r s'/z)$ is holomorphic in $r < |z| < s'$ and continuous and zero on the boundary of that annulus.